# OAuth2 using Curl/Node.js is not giving any response

Tags: node.js, curl, oauth-2.0, access-token, postman

I'm able to sucessfully create the Access token using postman with following parameters, 
Callback URL: https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback
Token Name:
Auth URL:
Access Token URL:
Client ID:
Client Secret:
Grant Type:Client Credentials.

But I could not able to get the access token via Curl or node.js as below,

```
var request = require("request");
var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: '',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
  body: '{"client_id":"","client_secret":"","audience":","grant_type":"client_credentials"}' };
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) console.log(error);
  //console.log(response);
  console.log(body);
});
```

where I mapped my postman details to node.js script as,

```
Auth URL: url
Access Token URL: audience
Client Id: client_id
Client Secret: client_secret
Grant Type: grant_type
```

But I didn't any response. May I Know where i went wrong? or do we have any other mechanism to get the OAuth2 access token?

I'm just followed the script from https://manage.auth0.com/#/apis/590983763e3ae44a0dd1a219/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few research, I myself found the solution to generate the OAuth2 token through the code using the request, and I mapped by Postman values into the request_options as,

```
const options = {
  url: access_token_url,
  method: 'POST',
  auth: {
    user: client_id,
    pass: client_secret,
  },
  form: {
    grant_type: grant_type,
  },
};
```

and used the request method to get the access token by,

```
request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      return resolve(body);
    });
```

This helps me to generate the OAuth2 access token inside my script and fixed my requirement.